# Passing specified template type as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-templates

Say I have some template type...

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {
    Foo(T t) {}
};
```

Is there a way to pass a specified Foo type to a function so that the function has direct visibility of T?

Ideally I would be able to write something like this...

```
Foo<int> foo = create<Foo<int>>();
```

The closest I've been able to come is

```
template <
    template <typename> typename TT,
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<TT<T>, Foo<T>>::value, int> = 0
>
Foo<T> create() {
    return Foo<T>(T());
}
```

which would then be used like

```
Foo<int> foo = create<Foo, int>();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So, essentially, you want a `create` function that takes as a template type only a `Foo<T>` and returns a `Foo<T>`?

Comment: Couldn't it simply be `Foo<int> foo = createFoo<int>();` - as the constructed type will always be `Foo<T>` anyway?

Comment: @axalis yes, I could do `createFoo<T>()` instead of `create<Foo<T>>()`, however I'm looking for a solution that I can generalize for other types, e.g. `create<TType<T>>`

Comment: @Daskie see my edited answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This form of template template parameter is only allowed in C++17:

```
template < //           v---------- typename here not allowed
    template <typename> typename TT,
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<TT<T>, Foo<T>>::value, int> = 0
>
Foo<T> create() {
    return Foo<T>(T());
}
```

You must replace the `typename` pointed out by `class`:

```
template < //           v---------- class allowed
    template <typename> class TT,
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<TT<T>, Foo<T>>::value, int> = 0
>
Foo<T> create() {
    return Foo<T>(T());
}
```

In C++17, both compiles and are equivalent.

---

To make your syntax `Foo<int> foo = create<Foo<int>>();` work, you simply need to do this:

```
template <typename T>
T create() {
    return T{};
}
```

If you want to limit what type can be sent, you must create a type trait:

```
// default case has no typedef
template<typename>
struct first_param {};

// when a template is sent, define the typedef `type` to be equal to T
template<template<typename> class TT, typename T>
struct first_param<TT<T>> {
    using type = T;
};

// template alias to omit `typename` everywhere we want to use the trait.
template<typename T>
using first_param_t = typename first_param<T>::type;
```

Then, use your trait:

```
template <
    typename T, 
    void_t<first_param_t<T>>* = nullptr
> //       ^---- if the typedef is not defined, it's a subtitution error.
T create() {
    return T(first_param_t<T>{});
}
```

You can implement `void_t` like this:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

<kbd>[Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9245243806112a25)</kbd>

Comment: I don't think this the the issue as it appears to compile for the OP.  The question seems to be how to "fix" the template to allow one to write `Foo<int> foo = create<Foo<int>>();` instead of `Foo<int> foo = create<Foo, int>();`

Comment: Awesome.  Should work now no matter what the OP wants.  +1

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply use a tag dispatching, e.g.:

```
template <class>
struct tag { };

template <class T>
Foo<T> create(tag<Foo<T>>) {
    return Foo<T>(T());
}

//...

Foo<int> foo = create(tag<Foo<int>>{});
```

Comment: This would absolutely work, but I am looking for a solution without function parameters.

Comment: @Daskie reconsider your architecture - the function call will be optimised by a compiler like it wouldn't have any parameter anyway...

Answer (score 4):

One simple way is to add the sub-type information in `Foo` directly:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {
    using type = T;
    Foo(T t) {}
};
```

and then

```
template <typename FooT>
FooT create() {
    return FooT(typename FooT::type{});
}
```

You might add SFINAE if you want:

```
template <typename FooT>
auto create()
-> decltype(FooT(typename FooT::type{}))
{
    return FooT(typename FooT::type{});
}
```

If you want really restrict the function to `Foo` exclusively, you have to create a traits and SFINAE on it.

Comment: Traits and SFINAE seems like the way to go

Answer (score 2):

In C++11

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UKCMxCZKmI9YRaQ7)

The gist is to have an entry point function named `create` that can instantiate a `create_helper` struct to create the proper type.

We can create our structures using template specialization so that we're forcing a templated class to be passed.

#### Full code:

```
template<class T>
struct create_helper
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Need to pass templated type to create");
};

template <class T, template<class> class TT>
struct create_helper<TT<T>>
{
   static TT<T> apply()
   {
       return {T{}};
   }
};

template<class T>
auto create() -> decltype(create_helper<T>::apply())
{
    return create_helper<T>::apply();
}
```

And a test:

```
template<class T>
struct Foo
{
     Foo(T t){std::cout << "Constructed Foo with value " << t << std::endl;}
};
int main()
{ 
    Foo<int> foo = create<Foo<int>>();
}
```

Output:

```
Constructed Foo with value 0
```

Comment: Note that the base template `create_helper` does not need to die with a `static_assert`. If you'd like, you can add an `apply` function to create a default instance of `T` like we did with the specialization. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bAcedPFMk3I1svmI)